# OAuth2 - Spring security: ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am implementing OAuth2 authentication and I totally don't understand why my CustomCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter does not work.

When I launch the application in debugging mode, neither of debug checkpoints is hit.

I need the filter to be overriden and change the implementation of authentication attempt.

Is there a mistake in my configuration?

Authentication Adapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.springapp.mvc")
@Order(3)
class OAuth2AuthenticationConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler oAuth2AccessDeniedHandler;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("clientDetailsService")
private ClientDetailsService oauth2ClientDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .anonymous()
            .disable();
    http
            .requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/token")
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .fullyAuthenticated();
    http
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(oAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint())
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(oAuth2AccessDeniedHandler);
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(clientDetailsUserDetailsService());
}

@Bean
ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter() {
    final ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter tokenEndpointFilter = new CustomClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter();
    try {
        tokenEndpointFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        tokenEndpointFilter.setAuthenticationEntryPoint(oAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint());
        tokenEndpointFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        tokenEndpointFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler());
        tokenEndpointFilter.setAllowOnlyPost(true);
        return tokenEndpointFilter;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}

@Bean
OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler oAuth2AccessDeniedHandler() {
    return new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler();
}

AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
    return new OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler();
}

AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
    return new OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler();
}

UserDetailsService clientDetailsUserDetailsService() {
    final ClientDetailsUserDetailsService service = new ClientDetailsUserDetailsService(oauth2ClientDetailsService);

    return service;
}

@Bean
OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint oAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint() {
    final OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
    entryPoint.setRealmName("oauth/client");
    entryPoint.setTypeName("Basic");
    return entryPoint;
}

static final class CustomClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter extends ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter {

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        final Authentication authentication = super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);

        return authentication;
    }
}

static final class OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String s = request.toString();
    }
}

static final class OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String s = request.toString();
    }
}

}
```

Http request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic **************************" -v -d "username=my.user&password=pass&client_id=my.user&cla-7c9d-426b-a942-cc166438f996&grant_type=password&scope=[read, write]" http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
```

Log after invoking request.

```
 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is error=&quot;invalid_client&quot;, error_description=&quot;Given client ID does not match authenticated client&quot;
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:943)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:833)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:201)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
 </pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>error=&quot;invalid_client&quot;, error_description=&quot;Given client ID does not match authenticated client&quot;
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory.createTokenRequest(DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory.java:104)
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(TokenEndpoint.java:81)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:833)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:201)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

I know where the exception occurs and what causes it and in order to fix this I must provide custom filter.

Comment: Do you know if Spring is even initializing your filter and beans? On start-up, with debug logging enabled, Spring will actually print all your filter chains. Check that your filter shows up on the /oauth/token context.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Misha. I was aware that Spring initializes filter chaining and beans on start-up. The problem is that I don't know why the registered filter is not invoked. When I send requests with curl it this filter should be also invoked. But it is not. Any ideas why?

Comment: That's not quite what I meant. Can you verify in your logs that the appropriate filter chain does, in fact, carry an instance of your filter?

Comment: I updated curl request exception log. My filter is not invoked on start-up.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the explanation can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/wiki/oAuth2). If you decide to use custom filter, you cannot use it with

> /oauth/token

path.

However, I tried to implement custom token endpoint and I didn't succeed with path mapping. [Someone did and here is the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222966/how-to-change-spring-security-oauth2-default-token-endpoint).