# Spring Security OAuth2 Refresh Token

Tags: spring-security

We are using Spring Security OAuth2 service. 
We maintain a blacklist of refresh tokens in memory. Whenever the Authorization server gets a request with the refresh token (to renew the user token), we want to validate against this blacklist.

What is the Spring call back method where I can make this check? 
We have looked at JDBCApprovalStore, but are looking for a more simpler solution only for invalidation of refresh tokens.

Comment: Have you tried removing the refresh token from `TokenStore`?

Comment: That way you probably wouldn't need a blacklist. Another option is to [override the default refresh token endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222966/how-to-change-spring-security-oauth2-default-token-endpoint#answer-27860080) in `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer` and provide your own one.

Comment: I am using JWT. Hence there is no token store actually.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to your problem?